# Google Places API: How can I select pac-container class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Why I'm not able to select `pac-container` class.

I'm using Google Places API

See below screenshots of `pac-container` class:-

[image]

What is tried:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.pac-container', function() {
    alert('pac container class selected');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this problem, Actually i was call my Jquery code inside `document.ready` but i need to use it inside `Place Autocomplete` code.

`Place Autocomplete` was load before load my custom jquery that is given in question but custom jquery should be load with `Place Autocomplete`.

**Now taken my code inside a function:-**

```
function ZipOrCityOnMobile() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.m-search-close').hide();
        $('[name="ZipOrCity"]').parents('li').removeClass('search-control-mobile');
        $('.home-text').css('z-index', '9');
    }
}
```

**Then it called inside `Place Autocomplete`**

```
function initOfficeLocationAddLocationPicker() {
        var input = document.getElementById('ZipOrCity');
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
         // Set country for us.
        places.setComponentRestrictions({ 'country': ['us'] });
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var address = AddressHepler(places.getPlace());
            if (address.postal_code != null && address.postal_code != '' && address.postal_code != undefined) {
                var CityStateandZipcode = address.locality.concat(', ', address.state, ', ', address.postal_code);
                $("#ZipOrCity").val(CityStateandZipcode);
            }
            else if (address.locality != null && address.locality != '' && address.locality != undefined) {
                var CityandState = address.locality.concat(', ', address.state);
                $("#ZipOrCity").val(CityandState);
            }
            else {
                $("#ZipOrCity").val(address.state);
            }
            ZipOrCityOnMobile();
        });
    }
```